# Getting Azure AD domain via Bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

Bicep provides functions to retrieve information regarding the context of the deployment. I have looked at `environment()` and `subscription()` functions and both don't have the AAD Domain.

Is there a way of getting AAD domain, e.g. "example.com" from Bicep?

Comment: There is a tenant function but it does not seem to return the domain, only tenantId: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-scope#tenant

Comment: @Thomas and I am actually using it to get the tenantId already, but couldn't find the domain

Comment: Is this still not possible to get via Bicep somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Current Bicep works only with Azure Resource Manager APIs:

- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/7724

One solution is to use deployment scripts(1) and then fetch required information from graph API.

(1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template